# Testing wallet password

Tags: wallets, security

I finally got my wallet to work. I am just wondering is there a way that I can test to ensure I remember the wallet password correctly? I mean the last thing that I want to send a large number of ethereum to my wallet that I don't remember the password to.

Comment: Which wallet are you using?

Comment: Ethereum wallet (desktop) the standard one

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your keyfile (named `UTC--<created_at UTC ISO8601>-<address hex>`) is in the default folder:

```
Win: %APPDATA%\Ethereum\keystore\UTC--2018-04-29T16-31-49.067329700Z--328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca
     (i.e. c:\Users\traxium\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore\UTC--2018-04-29T16-31-49.067329700Z--328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca)
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum/keystore/UTC--2018-04-29T16-31-49.067329700Z--328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca
Linux: ~/.ethereum/keystore/UTC--2018-04-29T16-31-49.067329700Z--328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca
```

Install [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) (it's likely already installed together with Ethereum Wallet).

Run:

```
> geth account list
INFO [07-08|07:42:32] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
Account #0: {328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca} keystore://C:\Users\traxium\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore\UTC--2018-04-29T16-31-49.067329700Z--328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca
```

To list the accounts available and:

```
> geth account update 328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca
INFO [07-08|07:49:48] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
Unlocking account 328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca | Attempt 1/3
Passphrase:
Unlocking account 328830117705193c92fbc7aaf675f3e21d6223ca | Attempt 2/3
Passphrase:
INFO [07-08|07:50:53] Unlocked account   address=0x328830117705193C92fBc7aaf675f3e21d6223CA
Please give a new password. Do not forget this password.
Passphrase:
```

To attempt to update the password to the wallet. If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> before changing your password, you can use it to verify your password (don't be afraid of `Attempt 1/3` message, you have unlimited amount of attempts, your wallet won't be blocked after 3 unsuccessful attempts, you will just have to run `geth account update <address>` again and have 3 more guesses).

---

You will probably be unable to test your password by sending a small amount of ether to another account. When sending ether in Ethereum Wallet with a wrong password it goes to very long (probably infinite) `CONFIRMING...` without any indication whether the guessed password was correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

The most bulletproof way to test any new wallet is to send a tiny amount of ether into it and then send the ether back out again. It is an excellent idea to do this any time you are using new wallet software.